# spring security 4 prioritize roles

Tags: spring, spring-security, roles

I am wondering about the possibilities in spring security 4 to prioritize the roles to access a given url:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/service/hello/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
}
```

By prioritize I mean I can build up a role tree where Admin > Smaller Admin > User > Almost User > Anonymus and when I tell hasRole on an url, an Admin is also a User so it can view a hasRole("USER") page or it can call the rest service on it.

Is this possible or just hasAnyRole(..) and hasAnyAuthority(..) are the 2 possible choices with a list of roles?

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#authz-hierarchical-roles)?

Comment: The documentation is big and I am small, thanks for pointing out the important part.